# Update depth map on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, functional-programming

I have a global fixed depth gradient of an image `G(x,y)` and two depth cues including:

1. Texture variation feature `T(x,y)` that is extracted by applying
   laws' texture energy masks to the luma information of each block.
2. Perspective (edge information) feature `E(x,y)` that is extracted by applying Radon Transform to the luma information of each block within the image.

Now I want to refine the depth map based on the extracted features using: the global depth, a linear function of the edge information `f(E(x,y))` that is monotonically decreasing, and a linear function of the texture energy `f(T(x,y))` that is monotonically increasing.

This can be represented in the following equation:

```
d(x,y) = G(x,y)f(T(x,y))f(E(x,y))
```

My question is: How can I make the texture energy `T(x,y)` monotonically decreasing linear function and the edge information `E(x,y)` monotonically increasing linear function in MATLAB? And how to use them then to refine the depth map?